# Variable set in pipe and tab function is not detected by *ngif

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

I have the following code that gets data from a search control and calls a method to get results. While the results are being returned a progress bar should display within the auto complete options.

Here is the type script:

```
this.form.get("queryResult")!.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(800), // Wait for 800ms after each keystroke before considering the term
        filter((value) => typeof value === 'string'), // Only proceed if the value is a string
        tap((value) => {
          this.searchText = value; // Update the search text
          this.loading = value.length >= this.minSearchLength;
        }),
        filter((value) => value.length >= this.minSearchLength), // Only proceed if search term is at least minSearchLength characters long
        switchMap((value) => this.searchService.search(this.form.get('scope')?.value, value)) // Call the search service
      )
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.options = response; // Set the search results
        this.loading = false; // Set loading to false after getting the results
      });
```

and here is the mark up:

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" (optionSelected)="selectedItem = $event.option.value">
      <mat-option *ngIf="loading" disabled>
        Loading...
        <mat-progress-bar mode="query"></mat-progress-bar>
      </mat-option>
      <ng-container *ngIf="!loading">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option" class="full-width">
          <div>
            <strong>{{option.name}}</strong>
            <p>{{option.code}}</p>
          </div>
        </mat-option>
      </ng-container>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</ng-container>
```

The problem is that when the loading variable is set to true in the tap function *ngif does not detect the change in value. Note that this is NOT the case in the subscribe method where the value is set to false.

Is there something specific about the tap method?

Comment: Nothing specific with the tap. Is you ChangeDetectionStrategy set to `OnPush` ?

Comment: I just tried a simplified version of this and it worked fine once I added a delay. Maybe your switchMap is occurring too quickly to see it? The code I used is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wwxj6w

Comment: Are you 100% that value is a string and getting through your filter?

Comment: Thanks for the replies - I think it is that my switchMap is returning too quickly and the point in time I was expecting to see the progress bar is actually the debounce time. Adding a delay enables me to see it as DeborahK suggested